# Is there a way to use Unicode paths/filenames in Word 2003 or higher VBA code?

Tags: vba, unicode, ms-word, powerpoint, word-2003

Is there a way to use Unicode paths/filenames in Word 2003 or higher VBA code?

It appears that Word supports Unicode path/filenames via its interactive dialogues, but when our VBA code tries to manipulate Unicode path/filenames exposed via Word properties, we get back strings with lots of question marks.

Is there something we need to do have Word VBA work in a Unicode mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's a real pain. I've been using [this](http://teaandbiscuits.org.uk/drupal/node/77), which has been very helpful. There are ways to manually build this support directly in VBA. A couple of searches turned up things like [this](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scrIpts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=UnicodeWordMacrosIntro).

Note that this still won't help with the dialogs, etc. as they are set to the LocaleID of the OS (so if you change your OS display language to the local language, they should appear just fine).

Comment: Otaku: Thank you very much for your links - just what we needed. Regards, Malcolm